# How to replace a file in local repo with another one from remote repo?

Tags: git, git-pull

I did tried lots of approaches but I don't get what's really happening and how to fix it:

There are two git repos: remote and local (on my machine). 
Since I'm studying I experiment with code and do many changes in my local files. Usually then I do a revert for every file been changed then and I pull actual version of project from remote repo.
But now I have one file (for example `hello.jsp`) that was changed by me and those changes were committed. And after that I have committed few times other changes related to other files. 
Well now I want to replace my local `hello.jsp` with same file from remote repo. So I did `git pull --rebase` and got merge conflict:

```
Applying: merge fixed
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
M       hello.jsp
<stdin>:10: trailing whitespace.
    function showHello() {
<stdin>:11: trailing whitespace.

<stdin>:12: trailing whitespace.
        document.getElementById('q').style.display = 'none';
<stdin>:13: trailing whitespace.
        document.getElementById('w').style.display = 'none';
<stdin>:14: trailing whitespace.
        document.getElementById('e').style.display = '';
warning: squelched 120 whitespace errors
warning: 125 lines add whitespace errors.
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
Auto-merging hello.jsp
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in hello.jsp
Failed to merge in the changes.
Patch failed at 0001 merge fixed
The copy of the patch that failed is found in:
   d:/repo/helloProject/.git/rebase-apply/patch

When you have resolved this problem, run "git rebase --continue".
If you prefer to skip this patch, run "git rebase --skip" instead.
To check out the original branch and stop rebasing, run "git rebase --abort".
```

well..First I tried to manually delete all changes I remember. But even if I use some kind of "show diff" it takes to much time to find all details were changed (believe me "hello.jsp" is very huge)
Shame on me but I can't get what to do now.

I tried to do `git reset "hello.jsp"` and tried to do `git checkout "hello.jsp"` but it did not work. How just simply replace my "hello.jsp" with another one from remote repo?

Comment: Can't you just solve the merge conflict in hello.jsp? Open it, search for strings `<<<<<<<<`, and choose which version you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to checkout the file that you want. You have to specify the place from where you want it.

```
git checkout your_remote/your_branch filename
```

Comment: @Piguerias, thx a lot. "git checkout origin "hello.jsp" made the thing I wanted". So it seems when I use checkout without pointing branch then it used my local "hello.jsp"..

Comment: @java_newbie It's using master by default if you don't specify one branch.