# In Git, is it possible to update a single file in local branch from remote master

Tags: git

I cloned a remote repository in GIT and local master got created. Now, after a few days, it seems that remote Master has progressed. Is it possible to take update from remote master for only one single file keeping other files as is.

Comment: try :
git checkout -- <path to your file>  
(note that above command will discard the changes which exists in file, in your local directory)

Comment: @user1562655 You should put that into an answer so that the OP can accept it as a solution. I believe what you wrote is already a complete answer to this question.

Comment: @MaxLeske : So what should I do now? delete my comment??

Comment: @user1562655 Just post it again as the Answer, thanks.

Comment: @Karun Have you done changes to your single file that you want to keep? Why do you want the other files intact? If they have progressed on remove, why don't you want the updates to be on your local branch?

Comment: I answered the same question today: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18911802/how-to-replacefile-in-local-repo-with-another-one-from-remote-repo/18911916#18911916. Anyway, why don't you the other updated files?

Comment: I just want one file because other changes are related to some other module which I don't want to incorporate in my local branch till I complete my module tests

Answer (score 4, accepted):

git checkout -- "path to your file"

(note that above command will discard the changes which exists in file, in your local directory)

Comment: Reposting from comments to answer